# What makes a variable exist PHP?

Tags: php

I've been looking at the documentation for isset() on PHP's website at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php. The return value for this function is apparently as follows:

> Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise.

What is the difference between a variable which is set to NULL and a variable that is not set? Is it true that if `$variable = NULL`; `isset($variable)` would return FALSE, meaning the variable is NOT set?

EDIT: How would I then be able to distinguish between a variable whose value is NULL and a variable which does not exist?

Comment: `Is it true that if $variable = NULL; isset($variable) would return FALSE` Yes it is true, as you can [see for yourself](https://3v4l.org/09EKR)

Comment: [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: variable exists mean its defined somewhere before you use it and it has some value assigned other than NULL

Comment: *"How would I then be able to distinguish between a variable whose value is NULL and a variable which does not exist?"* -- does it make any difference to you? If yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between a variable which is set to NULL and a variable that is not set?

Take a look at [PHP types comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) table #1 (Comparisons of `$x` with PHP functions). The lines #2-#4 read:

```
| Expression      | gettype() | empty() | is_null() | isset() | if($x) |
|-----------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------|
| $x = null;      | NULL      | TRUE    | TRUE      | FALSE   | FALSE  |
| var $x;         | NULL      | TRUE    | TRUE      | FALSE   | FALSE  |
| $x is undefined | NULL      | TRUE    | TRUE      | FALSE   | FALSE  |
```

Can you spot any difference between them? Me neither.

There is one difference, though. When a variable `$x` is undefined, [`gettype($x)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php), [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php), `if($x)` and any code that attempts to get its value triggers a notice (*"Notice: Undefined variable: x"*). [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) do not trigger any error, warning or notice when their argument does not exist because their purpose is to classify the presence and value of their argument.

> How would I then be able to distinguish between a variable whose value is `NULL` and a variable which does not exist?

Apart from the notice triggered as explained above, there is no difference between a variable whose value is `NULL` and a variable that doesn't exist. Even the notice is just a hint about a possible error in the code or a way to improve its readability but with or without it, the behaviour is the same.

I cannot figure out any practical usage of telling apart an undefined variable from a variable that stores `NULL`.

> What makes a variable exist PHP?

A variable exist in PHP since it was assigned a value for the first time until it is [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) or until the code exits [its scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) (whichever comes first).